# Maven - Dependency on module for Checkstyle not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, checkstyle

Project Link: https://github.com/randomquestion/MultiModuleMavenCheckstyleSample

I have a very simple Maven project with multiple modules. I'm following [this Maven guide](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html) to enable Checkstyle on it. So I created a common module named `build-tools` (as per guide) and added Checkstyle configuration in root pom file. However I'm running to a very weird issue.

When I create a new Maven project from scratch, `mvn clean install` seems to work just fine including Checkstyle. However as soon as I rename the checkstyle file and update `pom.xml` with new name, build starts failing with the error `Could not find resource <new Checkstyle file name>`. After that, I can never get it to build again. The problem it seems is that the dependency on `build-tools` module in root pom is not working.

```
├── build-tools
│   ├── build-tools\ (1).iml
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│       └── main
│           └── resources
│               └── default-checkstyle.xml
├── pom.xml
```

Root pom.xml:

```
<modules>
  <module>build-tools</module>
</modules>

<properties>
  <checkstyle.config.location>default-checkstyle.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
</properties>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>validate</id>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <configuration>
            <configLocation>default-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
            <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

build-tools pom.xml

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>build-tools</name>
```

Error:

```
INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] my-app
[INFO] build-tools
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/../workspace/my-app/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) @ my-app ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] my-app ............................................. FAILURE [  1.170 s]
[INFO] build-tools ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.291 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-13T22:25:26-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) on project my-app: Failed during checkstyle execution: Unable to find configuration file at location: default-checkstyle.xml: Could not find resource 'default-checkstyle.xml'. -> [Help 1]
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong? Why is `mvn install` not building `build-tools` module first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current setup will not work! When I cloned your project and tried to build, it will definitely fail as I do not have `build-tool` artifact in my local repository while building the parent pom.

This is the structure you should have:

```
 -- build-tools
  |   |
  |   - pom.xml
  |
  - my app
  |   |
  |   - src
  |   - pom.xml
  |
  - pom.xml
```

Here is the parent `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
 <artifactId>my-app-parent</artifactId>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <name>my-app-parent</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <!--
   ~ Modules
 -->
 <modules>
   <module>build-tools</module>
   <module>my-app</module>    
 </modules>

 <build>
   <!--
     ~ Plugin Settings
   -->
   <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.17</version>
         <dependencies>
           <dependency>
             <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
             <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
             <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           </dependency>
         </dependencies>
         <executions>
           <execution>
             <id>validate</id>
             <phase>validate</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>check</goal>
             </goals>
           </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
           <configLocation>my-app-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
 </build>

 <reporting>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.17</version>
       <configuration>
         <configLocation>default-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </reporting>
</project>
```

build-tools/pom.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
</project>
```

Your other projects/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
     <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
     <artifactId>my-app-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Rename checkstyle file name as `build-tools/src/main/resources/my-app-checkstyle.xml`

Comment: I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/randomquestion/MultiModuleMavenCheckstyleSample/pull/2)

Comment: Thanks! This works too but will fail if there are java sources in root/parent module. Another pull request that was submitted works for that case too.

Comment: Root module is `maven pom aggregator`, why do you think it should have sources?

Comment: If you still want to have source in parent, then probably i will say create a separate and standalone build-tools project which will cater to all your other projects as a external dependency. `build-tools` separate project follow it's own release cadence and you need to deploy this artifact to your internal repository so that other projects can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Accrding to the [same document](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html). You should try and configure the plugin settings apart from the `<dependency>`(in the `<build>` tag) in the `<reporting>` tag as:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <configuration>
         <configLocation>default-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
         <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
         <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
         <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: That doesn't look the issue. I think the issue is that the dependency on module build-tools in checkstyle configuration is not working correctly. That's why when I rename the file, it fails.

Comment: @RandomQuestion do you mean, renaming this to `checkstyle.xml` works fine for you?

Comment: Yes. it works with original file name. Another way I verified it was I created a brand new project with both root pom and build-tools module. If I run mvn install on root directly, it can't find the jar of build-tools which indicates it's not building build-tools first.